# Why do I get fatal error:sstream no such file or direcrory in graphics.h in codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks, bgi, winbgi

I want to use `graphics.h` in **`codeblocks 16.01`** .

I have downloaded **`winbgi`** library and copied `graphics.h` and `winbgim.h` in include folder of `codeblocks` and `libbgi.a` in lib folder but when I am using it in a program I am getting:

> `error-fatal error:sstream no such file or directory`

Comment: winbgim is a C++ library, you simply can't use it with C directly

Comment: Kindly read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Change the source file's extension from `.c` to `.cpp` and try re-compiling.